# What's the difference between FTP and protobuf?

Tags: ftp, protocols, protocol-buffers

This question might be really stupid.  They are both protocols, right? So what's the difference between them?

Comment: They both are protocols but in general are not comparable. If you specify a particular perspective - the community might help, but the question asked as-is barely has any reasonable answer.

Comment: click on the tags and then "Learn more..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Protocol* is a very generic term. FTP is a network protocol which defines how client and server interact with each other in order to transfer data. protobuf is instead a description how structured data should be serialized, for example in order to transport the data over a network but also to store the data locally.

Thus, FTP is more like a car traveling on the street while protobuf describes how you put all the various luggage in the car, how you pack your bags etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really like your examples.